Registering Serilog with Logging.AddSerilog vs Services.AddSerilog
There are two ways to register Serilog.
The "old" way (shown in countless SO questions and tutorials):
//builder.Logging.ClearProviders();    // optional
builder.Logging.AddSerilog();

And the "new" way (shown in the current documentation):
builder.Services.AddSerilog();

Both are supported. How do they differ?

I found the answer in a related repo issue and blog post:

builder.Logging.AddSerilog adds Serilog as an additional provider to the logging pipeline
builder.Services.AddSerilog sets Serilog as the sole provider (thus the ClearProviders call is unnecessary)
builder.Host.UseSerilog forwards to builder.Services.AddSerilog; obsolete

Typically one would want to use builder.Services.AddSerilog.
